# How to check if my language is context-free can't seem to solve it using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

I have a language and I am trying to see if it's context-free or not, by trying to use a pumping-lemma but I can't figure it out, been reading a lot of other posts but still struggling to apply it to my example

this is the language (sorry for using an image, i know how to write number exponents but i don't know how to write letters as exponents): [image: language in question whether it's context-free or not]

Thanks

Comment: The pumping lemma for CFLs is a statement that is true voor all CFLs, so you can only use it to prove that a language is not CF by showing the lemma doesn't hold. At first glance this language looks CF to me because I can imagine a pushdown automaton accepting it. Try that approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, if it looks CF for you could you help me write a CFG for this , because i am still learning them and I wanna see if i can come up with the same CFG you would come up with

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way, instead of using images. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: The html tag `<sup>w</sup>` will also create superscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can proof that a language is CF by constructing a CFG or a PDA for it. I will give an example CFG for this language.

Let the start symbol be $S$.

In the definition we see that we can add arbitrarily many $m$'s, and for each $m$ there have to be two $t$'s.
$$M \rightarrow mMtt|\epsilon$$

The same for the $e$'s, but now with one $t$ fot each $e$.
$$E \rightarrow tEe|\epsilon$$

Then finally, there has to be an extra $t$. This gives following CFG:

$$S \rightarrow MtE$$
$$M \rightarrow mMtt|\epsilon$$
$$E \rightarrow tEe|\epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, comparing it with another language items in brackets should be read as powers, i can't type them in here: L1 = {d(2r)p(z)f(r)p(z)d(r) | r, z >= 0}  this language looks pretty similar to me could you please show me a CFG for it too in by editing your post? again Thank a lot again starting to become clearer